# How to best target toggle() function at complexity of child class

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to add read more toggle to a dynamiccally generated paragraph of long text.
i only need help with targeting my toggle at particular sections in my code. but the code is so mixed up that its become tricky to do

see attached. 
I want my -a- tag (with .morelink class) to target 2 lines (highlighted in yellow - see screenshot attached).

```
$(".morelink").click(function(){
//i need to replace the following code with the correct one to target the those 2 lines
  $(this).parent().sibling().prev().toggle();
  $(this).prev().toggle();
```

[image: apply readmore toggle to a dynamically generated text]

Comment: so you want when you click on `read more` to show  the `more content` ? and what about the `more elipses` ?

Comment: Next time please refrain from posting code as an image. It would be more helpful to us if you posted your code as a snippet. Now in order to show you an example we have to type in your code by hand, instead of just copying it. Also using snippets makes it possible to run the code on StackOverflow. [http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget you can combine your `jQuery` selectors :

```
$(this).prev().find('.moreellipses,.morecontent>span').toggle();
```

- `.prev()` select the element previous to your link
- `.find('.moreellipses')` will select the element with the class `moreellipses` inside the element previous to your link.
- `.find('.morecontent>span')` will select the direct child span from the element with the class `morecontent` inside the element previous to your link.